# How can I update as random values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little PHP script like this;

I want to UPDATE rank from those 18 different types of level.

```
//Getting values
$getir=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE bot='1'");
//First level
$level1="Ayakci";
// While for all
while($getirx=mysql_fetch_array($getir)) {
    echo $getirx[0] . "<br>";
    $guncelle=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank='$level1' WHERE bot='1'");
    //Pick a random level1 while exiting while
    $seviye1=rand(1,18);
    if($seviye1==1){
        $level1="Baron";
    } elseif($seviye1==2){
        $level1="Patron";
    } elseif($seviye1==3){
        $level1="Baskan";
    } elseif($seviye1==4){
        $level1="Lider";
    } elseif($seviye1==5){
        $level1="Mit Ajani";
    } elseif($seviye1==6){
        $level1="Efsane";
    } elseif($seviye1==7){
        $level1="Efsanevi Baba";
    } elseif($seviye1==8){
        $level1="Baba";
    } elseif($seviye1==9){
        $level1="Isadami";
    } elseif($seviye1==10){
        $level1="Tetikci";
    } elseif($seviye1==11){
        $level1="Suclu";
    } elseif($seviye1==12){
        $level1="Seri Katil";
    } elseif($seviye1==13){
        $level1="Kiralik Katil";
    }elseif($seviye1==14){
        $level1="Katil";
    }elseif($seviye1==15){
        $level1="Hirsiz";
    }elseif($seviye1==16){
        $level1="Ozel Koruma";
    }elseif($seviye1==17){
        $level1="Bodyguard";
    }elseif($seviye1==18){
        $level1="Ayakci";
    }

    echo $level1 . "<br>";
}
```

It echoes random but NOT UPDATING "rank" value as random. It is picking a random $level1 and applies to all same.

It updates all bot='1' values but it applies same level to all of them.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: could you indent that code please? bit hard to read

Comment: What do you _want_ to update? Your statement works exactly as it is written. Update all rows where `bot=1` with the current value of `$level1`.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to add something like `AND username = '{$getirx[0]}'`

Comment: It echoes perfectly but at the database side, it updates ol bots with "same" level, not random.

Comment: Although my answer doesn't reflect this, I am re-reading OP question and interpreting it to mean this: *I want to assign a random rank to all users where bot = 1, however it is only assigning the same rank.*

Comment: become familiar with `switch/case` construct. it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok a few clean up items and suggestions:

First, you should strongly consider using a switch/case instead of multiple if/elseif:

```
switch ($seviye1)
{
    case 1:
        $level1 = "Baron";
        break;
    case 2:
        $level1 = "Patron";
        break;
    // and so on...
}
```

However, you may want to go a step further and define some arrays, and use the numbers you get back as a reference to the array index:

```
$avails = array
(
    "Baron",
    "Patron",
    "Baskan",
    "Lider",
    // et. al.
);

$seviye1 = rand(0, 17);
$level1 = $avails[$seviye1];
```

**EDIT:**

After further consideration, it appears you're trying to assign a random rank to all users who have a `bot` value of 1.

Here's how I would rewrite it:

```
// Get user id's having bot = 1
$getir = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE bot = 1;");

// Available levels
$avails = array
(
    "Baron", "Patron", "Baskan", "Lider",
    "Mit Ajani", "Efsane", "Efsanevi Baba", "Baba",
    "Isadami", "Tetikci", "Suclu", "Seri Katil",
    "Kiralik Katil", "Katil", "Hirsiz", "Ozel Koruma",
    "Bodyguard", "Ayakci"
);

// Update database; assign random levels to users
while($getirx = mysql_fetch_array($getir))
{
    echo $getirx[0] . "<br />";

    // Pick random level
    $level1 = $avails[rand(0, count($avails) - 1)];

    // Perform update
    $update_query = "UPDATE users SET rank = '$level1' WHERE bot = 1 AND username = '{$getirx[0]}';";
    $guncelle = mysql_query($update_query);
}
```

If it is somehow important that the first user be assigned the rank/level of "Ayakci" then you can add that back in; it is omitted from this example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's what you have been trying to achieve:

```
$guncelle=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank='".$level1."' WHERE bot='1' AND username = '".$getirx[0]."'");
```

Comment: Quotation marks in PHP have the effect of parsing for PHP variables. Thus there should be no reason to exit the string and concatenate `$level1` in. However adding username to the WHERE clause is probably key here. :)

Comment: It echoes perfectly, but not updating database in the same way. It applies one level to all values still.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
UPDATE users SET rank='$level1' WHERE bot='1'
```

Will update all records in the users table to the value of $level1 where bot equals 1.

It is running that with every loop, meaning the rank field will change on every record every time.

EDIT: I concur with  Michael Berkowski's second comment to your question.